# Por que este json é invalido?

Tags: php, json

Por que este json é valido:

```
    {
   "query":"mutation{ createCard(input: {pipe_id: 426174 fields_attributes: [{field_id: \"o_que\", field_value: \"Igor\"}{field_id: \"idade\", field_value: \"21\"}{field_id: \"cidade\", field_value: \"Vila Velha - ES\"}] parent_ids: [\"2735966\"] }) { card {id title }}}"
}
```

E este esta dando inválido nos testes que faço:

```
{"query":"mutation {
        createTableRecord(input: {
            table_id: \"RL-p4Ud_\"
            title: \"Igor Oliveira\"
            due_date: \"2018-04-10T11:04:57-03:00\"
            fields_attributes: [{
                field_id: \"nome_completo\",
                field_value: \"Igor Oliveira\"
            }, {
                field_id: \"e_mail\",
                field_value: \"xxxx@gmail.com\"
            }, {
                field_id: \"telefone\",
                field_value: \"279800002\"
            }]
        }) {
            table_record {
                id title
            }
        }"}
```

o erro é o seguinte:

> Invalid characters found.[Code 18, Structure 4]

A ideia é o query ter todo o mutation como se fosse uma string mesmo.

No PHP estou criando assim:

```
        $query = '{"query":"';
    $query .= 'mutation {
        createTableRecord(input: {
            table_id: \"RL-p4Ud_\"
            title: \"'.$nomecompleto.'\"
            due_date: \"'.date('c').'\"
            fields_attributes: [{
                field_id: \"nome_completo\",
                field_value: \"'.$nomecompleto.'\"
            }, {
                field_id: \"e_mail\",
                field_value: \"'.$email.'\"
            }, {
                field_id: \"telefone\",
                field_value: \"'.$telefone.'\"
            }]
        }) {
            table_record {
                id title
            }
        }';
      $query .= '"}';
```

Comment: Não é possível quebrar uma string de um valor em json em várias linhas. Por isso o segundo exemplo de json é invalido mesmo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Porque você quebrou linhas dentro das aspas `"..."`, o que vai invalidar o JSON, o que você pode fazer para resolver isto é antes de usar o `json_decode` ou de enviar para o output (`application/json`) é converter as linhas em `\\n` (e os "carrinhos" em `\\r`):

por exemplo:

```php
$query = '{"query":"';

$query .= 'mutation {
    createTableRecord(input: {
        table_id: \"RL-p4Ud_\"
        title: \"'.$nomecompleto.'\"
        due_date: \"'.date('c').'\"
        fields_attributes: [{
            field_id: \"nome_completo\",
            field_value: \"'.$nomecompleto.'\"
        }, {
            field_id: \"e_mail\",
            field_value: \"'.$email.'\"
        }, {
            field_id: \"telefone\",
            field_value: \"'.$telefone.'\"
        }]
    }) {
        table_record {
            id title
        }
    }';

 $query .= '"}';

 $query = strtr($query, array(
      "\r" => '\\r',
      "\n" => '\\n'
 ));

 echo $query;
```

Ou então você poderia simplificar e criar tudo via objeto ou array e depois usar o `json_encode`, o bom de fazer assim é que nem vai precisar ficar escapando caracteres como `"`, dentro da tua chave `query: "..."`, o próprio `json_encode` se encarrega do que for necessário.

Exemplo:

```php
$queryObj = [
    'query' => 'mutation {
        createTableRecord(input: {
            table_id: "RL-p4Ud_"
            title: "'.$nomecompleto.'"
            due_date: "'.date('c').'"
            fields_attributes: [{
                field_id: "nome_completo",
                field_value: "'.$nomecompleto.'"
            }, {
                field_id: "e_mail",
                field_value: "'.$email.'"
            }, {
                field_id: "telefone",
                field_value: "'.$telefone.'"
            }]
        }) {
            table_record {
                id title
            }
        }'
];

$query = json_encode($queryObj);

echo $query;
```

Comment: Isto mesmo, a solução que procurava era esta com a criação de um objeto, eu nao gosto de fazer tudo numa linha e colocar aquela monte de escape